# シーケンス図でフォームを使った認証処理を記述する場合、認証が成功するかどうかを条件にしてループ処理にした方が良いのか

Tags: uml, plantuml

現在、認証情報を入力する画面のシーケンス図を記述しています。認証が成功すれば次のページへ、情報に不備があればエラーを出し再度入力させるという処理の流れになっています。質問は、エラーがあるまで入力をし続ける必要がある場合、それはループ処理として書く必要があるのかということです。実際のコードではここはループ処理にはならないので間違っていると思っているのですが、単純な条件分岐にした場合、そのまま処理が終了するように見えると思いました。

今回のような流れを実現したい場合、どのように書くのが適切なのでしょうか。

[image: 記述したシーケンス図]

plantumlのコード

```
@startuml
actor       ユーザー       as user
participant UI as ui #skyblue
participant APIサーバー as api
database    DB    as db #yellow


user <- ui: 認証情報入力画面
loop
user -> ui: フォームを入力
activate ui
ui -> api: フォーム送信
activate api
api -> db: 該当ユーザーのデータ取得
activate db
api <- db: 完了
deactivate db
api -> api: 認証情報の照合
ui <- api: 認証結果の返却
deactivate api

alt 空の入力項目がある場合
  user <- ui: エラー「入力必須項目です。」

else 認証に失敗した場合
  user <- ui: エラー「認証に失敗しました。」

end

break 認証成功
  user <- ui: [[#1 次のページ]]
deactivate ui
  end
end

@enduml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

仮にループにしないとすると画面設計まで落とし込んだ時に
エラー画面を出して終了画面が出てきてもシーケンス図通りの設計であるといえてしまいます。
それでもいいということであればループを書く必要はありません。
しかしユーザにフォーム画面を表示させて繰り返し入力をしてもらうことを想定するならばユーザ都合のループを書くべきです。

シーケンス図の大事なことはコードの実装を書くことではなく、各オブジェクト間のやりとりを時系列に書くことです。
オブジェクトの仕様やふるまいは開発する部分だけではなく今回でいう「ユーザ」や「外部システム」いわゆる「外側」のふるまいも必要になります。
外側を書くことでどういった開発をするのかしないのかを明確に分けるためのドキュメントです。